# UI Text in Google VR doesn't work

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine, google-cardboard, virtual-reality

I am trying to have 2 UI texts that show how many wins/losses a player have. However, the only thing I have been able to is to show the texts when I set the canvas to World space. That's not what I want them to appear on the "eyes" in the left upper corner, so that when the player moves his head they move too and don't stay one place.

This is how it looks like now
[image: This is how it looks like now]

The text "New Text" shouldn't be in the game but on "eyes".

I want something like this:
[image]

Comment: you simply have to sit "something" in front of the camera (ie, "in front of the eyes") that moves around with the camera.  Exactly like the "gun" in a FPS.  If you want that to be an invisible panel, fine.

Comment: Have you tried this: https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/virtual-reality/user-interfaces-vr ?